# Moment Generating Function of Y=2^(-X), where X ~ Geom(1/2)

Tags: expected-value, moment-generating-functions, geometric-distribution

## My End Goal

To compute the following Expected value:
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E \;\left(\frac1{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{B} 2^{-X_i}}\right)$$

*where*:

- $B$ is a constant (e.g., $B=4096$)
- $X_i \sim Geom(\tfrac{1}{2})$ are independent Geometric random variables with $p=\tfrac{1}{2}$

  - $P(X_i =k)=\tfrac{1}{2}^k$, for $k\in \{1, 2, ...\}$

## My Plan so far:

We know that:

$$\E \left(\frac{1}{Y}\right)=\int_0^\infty M_Y(-t) \; dt$$

where $M_Y(t) = \E \left(e^{tY}\right)$ is the Moment Generating Function of random variable $Y$.

Therefore, I need to compute the $M_Y(t)$, *where* $Y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{B} Y_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{B} 2^{-X_i}$.

Due to the i.i.d property of $X_i$s, their moment generating functions are the same, and thus, we need one of them multiplied together $B$ times:

$$M_Y(t) = M_{Y_1}(t)^B$$

So, we just need to compute the term, $M_{Y_1}(t)$, *with* $Y_1 = 2^{-X_1}$.

> For simplification, from now on I will denote $X_1$ as $X$, and $Y_1$ as $Y$

### Now, the question is:

##### How to compute the MGF of $2^{-X}$, where $X \sim Geom(\frac{1}{2})$?

My attempt so far: if I expand the formula for MGF, I get the following:

\begin{align*}
M(t) & = \E \left(e^{t \cdot 2^{-X}} \right) \\
 & = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} \cdot e^{t \cdot 2^{-k}}  \\
 & = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{t}{2^k}}}{2^k} \\
 & = \tfrac{1}{2}e^{\frac{t}{2}} + \tfrac{1}{4}e^{\frac{t}{4}} + \tfrac{1}{8}e^{\frac{t}{8}} + \tfrac{1}{16}e^{\frac{t}{16}} + ...
\end{align*}

**But, I am not sure how to simplify the above equations** !!!!

I thought of the following strategy so far, which is to compute the moments themselves, and then have the MGF represented through these moments.

In other words,

\begin{align*}
M_Y(t) & = \E \left(e^{t Y} \right) \\
   & = 1 + t \E \left(Y\right) + \frac{t^2}{2!} \E \left(Y^2\right) + \frac{t^3}{3!} \E \left(Y^3\right) + ...
\end{align*}

And the fact that these $\E \left(Y^m\right)$ are easily calculable:
$$
\E \left(Y^m\right) = \E \left((2^{-X})^m\right)  = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (2^{-k})^m \cdot 2^{-k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k(m+1)} = \frac{1}{2^{m+1}-1}
$$

Plugging it in,
\begin{align*}
M_Y(t) & = 1 + \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)t + \left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\frac{t^2}{2!} + ... + \left(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}\right)\frac{t^n}{n!} + ...
\end{align*}

But, where do I go from there?